# Error when using .Net YouTube Data API, youtube.videos.insert

Tags: c#, video, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I am trying to upload av video to YouTube using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3 Client Library 1.8.1.1110 from a .Net 4.5 C# console app. I have created a service account, dowloaded a P12 key file and enabled the YouTube Data API v3.

This is my first attempt on any Google API and I might be missing the obvious.

I get the following error;

```
YouTube Data API: Upload Video
==============================
An error prevented the upload from completing.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
   ved Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   ved Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
   ved Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.<UploadAsync>d__0.MoveNext() i c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\output\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\[Media]\Upload\ResumableUpload.cs:linje 0
An error prevented the upload from completing.
System.ArgumentNullException: Verdien kan ikke være null.
Parameternavn: baseUri
   ved Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   ved Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
   ved Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.<UploadCoreAsync>d__e.MoveNext() i c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\output\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\[Media]\Upload\ResumableUpload.cs:linje 459
```

My code;

```
private async Task Run()
{
    String serviceAccountEmail = "xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

    ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
       new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
       {
           Scopes = new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload }
       }.FromCertificate(certificate));


    var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
    });


    var video = new Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data.Video();
    video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
    video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
    video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
    video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
    video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; 
    video.Status = new VideoStatus();
    video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted"; // or "private" or "public"
    var filePath = @"E:\OneDrive\CidWebApps\video.mp4"; 
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
        videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
        videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;


        await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
    }
}
```

Regards
Jon Ivar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload is not possible With Service accounts, see https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth#service_accounts.